# Recurse sub directories without creating those same sub directories in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I often use the `recursesubdirs` flag to traverse through a number of sub directories and extract a specific file or type of file without having to explicitly refer to each file individually. Example:

```
Source: C:\kh25\dependencies\*.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

This creates the exact same directory structure in my destination `{app}` path as the source from where the DLL was initially retrieved from. For example if I retrieved a DLL from `C:\kh25\dependencies\test` above then it would place that DLL in the `{app}\test` path.

This behaviour can be modified by doing this:

```
Source: C:\kh25\dependencies\test\*.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

But obviously this means I would have to reference each sub directory in dependencies individually.

So the $64,000 question is how can I prevent the same directory from being recreated in the destination without having to explicitly reference the source directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to generate the entries for the `[Files]` section.

One possible (and relatively nice and simple) solution is using a recursive macro like:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-

#define FileEntry(Source) \
    "Source: " + Source + "; DestDir: {app}\n"

#define ProcessFile(Source, FindResult, FindHandle) \
    FindResult \
        ? \
            Local[0] = FindGetFileName(FindHandle), \
            Local[1] = Source + "\\" + Local[0], \
            (Local[0] != "." && Local[0] != ".." \
                ? (DirExists(Local[1]) ? \
                    ProcessFolder(Local[1]) : FileEntry(Local[1])) \
                : "") + \
            ProcessFile(Source, FindNext(FindHandle), FindHandle) \
        : \
            ""

#define ProcessFolder(Source) \
    Local[0] = FindFirst(Source + "\\*", faAnyFile), \
    ProcessFile(Source, Local[0], Local[0])

#pragma parseroption -p+

#emit ProcessFolder("C:\kh25\dependencies")
```

Though this solution has its limit and may crash the preprocessor with large number of files or deep directory structure (works ok for thousands of files).

Inspired by the [answer by @Zlatko Karakaš](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883200/850848#36243818) to [Use Inno Setup PreProcessor to get the files and size of the source path and its subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883200/850848).

---

More reliable (and ugly and complex) solution is using a user defined procedures. It's complicated because the preprocessor lacks a support for parameters of user-defined procedures.

```
[Files]

#define FindHandle
#define FindResult 
#dim InnerMask[65536]
#define InnerMask[0] ""

#sub ProcessFoundFile
    #define InnerFileName FindGetFileName(FindHandle)
    #define fileName InnerMask[InnerMaskWorkPosition] + InnerFileName
    #if InnerFileName!="." && InnerFileName!=".."
        #if DirExists(FileName)
            #define Public InnerMask[InnerMaskPosition] FileName+"\"
            #define Public InnerMaskPosition InnerMaskPosition + 1
        #else
            Source: {#FileName}; DestDir: {app}
        #endif
    #endif 
#endsub

#sub ProcessInnerMaskPosition 
    #for { \
        FindHandle = FindResult = \
            FindFirst(InnerMask[InnerMaskWorkPosition]+"*", faAnyFile); \
        FindResult; FindResult = FindNext(FindHandle)} ProcessFoundFile
    #if FindHandle
        #expr FindClose(FindHandle)
    #endif
#endsub

#sub CollectFiles
    #define Public InnerMaskPosition 1
    #define Public InnerMaskWorkPosition 0
    #for { \
        InnerMaskWorkPosition = 0; InnerMaskWorkPosition < InnerMaskPosition; \
            InnerMaskWorkPosition++} \
            ProcessInnerMaskPosition
    #undef Public InnerMaskPosition
    #undef Public InnerMaskWorkPosition
#endsub

#expr InnerMask[0]="C:\kh25\dependencies\"
#expr CollectFiles
```

The recursive scan function taken from the [answer by @René Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883200/850848#25326796) to [Use Inno Setup PreProcessor to get the files and size of the source path and its subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20883200/850848).

---

Add a [`SaveToFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=savetofile) call at the *very end* of your Inno Setup script too see, what the preprocessor generates:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

See [Inno Setup: How do I see the output (translation) of the Inno Setup Preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328375/850848)

---

My answer to this question explains the differences between the two approaches taken above:
[Can Inno Setup Preprocessor be used to build a duplicated set of custom messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61991526/850848)

Comment: Thanks Martin. More work than I hoped but you can't win them all I suppose.