# How to recursivelly include folder/files using a wildcard in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, wildcard

I want to include language resource files from our build into our installers.  The language resource files all have the same name, but reside in different sub-folders (one per locale), like this:

```
\Release
  \bin
    \es-MX
      Localization.resources.dll
    \fr-CA
      Localization.resources.dll
etc.
```

In my `[Files]` section, I thought perhaps I might be able to do this (note the position of the asterisk):

```
Source: "..\\source\\Libraries\\Localization\\bin\\Release\\*\\Localization.resources.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

Unfortunately, Inno Setup blows up, complaining that it can't find any files:

> Compiler Error!
>   Line 129: No files found matching "C:\Development\HT\Installers\..\source\Libraries\Localization\bin\Release\*\Localization.resources.dll"

I would like Inno Setup to look for any sub-folder (hence the `*`) containing a file named `Localization.resources.dll` and upon installation, create a language directory with the same name (based on what is found via the wildcard) and copy the file to that folder, doing so for each folder that matches the criteria.

Essentially, I want to end up with this:

```
..
  \MyApp
    \es-MX
      Localization.resources.dll
    \fr-CA
      Localization.resources.dll
```

In case it isn't obvious, I would prefer not to explicitly add the source and destination folder names, because we will be adding more languages/locales in the future, and I would like Inno Setup to automatically pick up any new language folders/files we create without having to change the installer source.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`recursesubdirs` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=recursesubdirs) with a root path to a tree and the `Localization.resources.dll` filename. It will automatically do what you want: find all `Localization.resources.dll` files in the tree and install them to their respective subfolders:

```
Source: "..\source\Libraries\Localization\bin\Release\Localization.resources.dll"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

As [documented](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=recursesubdirs) (emphasis mine):

> **recursesubdirs**
>
> Instructs the compiler or Setup **to also search** for the **Source filename**/wildcard **in subdirectories** under the Source directory.

---

Other possible approaches:

- Generate the `Files` section using a preprocessor.

  For a similar tasks, see:

  - [Inno Setup - Recurse sub directories without creating those same sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36742636/850848)
  - [Generating Inno Setup file flags programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40728147/850848)
  - [Inno Setup: Dynamically add a component for all files in a folder and its subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45059158/850848)
- Generate the `Files` section using an external scripting language (with better functionality than Inno Setup preprocessor) and invoke it using the [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec). E.g. using PowerShell.